# Ansible - run plays on continously instead of linear

Tags: ansible

I have a list of hosts and roles to apply on each. They are hosted on a hypvervisor (XenServer / ESX).

I'm trying to **revert** each machine back to **snapshot** before executing the ansible plays. My flow of actions looks like this:

1. Take VM name from a file (machines.txt)
2. Connect the Hypervisor and through CLI revert the machine snapshot
3. Once SSH is up for the machine, connect and execute rest of the plays
4. Execute one machine at a time.

The best I came so far is executing the **revert** task on the hypervisor in one play, and then a different play to apply the roles. So that's how my playbook looks like:

```
---
  - name: Reverting
    hosts: xenhost
    tasks:
      - include_tasks: tasks/vms/revert_snap.yml
        with_lines: cat "machines.txt"

  - name: Ensure NTP is installed
    hosts: temp
    roles:
      - ntp
```

---

The solution I've found so far is,

1. Execute a task of **reverting snapshot from CLI** and execute it *on the Hypervisor*
2. Execute my whole maintenance play *on the machines*
   2.1 Wait for SSH on each
   2.2 Apply roles
3. Clean up and take new snapshots *on the Hypervisor*

The drawback I have in this scenario is, first it reverts ALL machines, then apply all the roles and then reverting all of them in bulk.
I can't combine the tasks into a single play because they are executed on different hosts.

Any better solutions? - which will revert one machine, apply all roles, take snapshot, then continue to the next machine.

Answer (score 0):

`Any better solutions? - which will revert one machine, apply all roles, take snapshot, then continue to the next machine.`

you could group all those tasks in a role, and execute the role with `serial: 1`

```
- hosts: hostgroup
  serial: 1
  roles:
    - {role: rolename }
```

Comment: My problem is the first play needs to be run on one host group, then the other tasks needs to run on another group

Comment: Understand now. Haven't used it in my work, and cant say for sure, but perhaps the answer to your problem is the `delegate_to` option. You could remove the snapshot related task, and integrate it to the role, using the `delegate_to`. when ansible runs the role to each of your machines, it will try to delegate the snapshot management task to the hypervisor.  Adding the `serial 1` to the picture, you get what you need. Worths to try this i think. [documentation for delegation here](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html)

Comment: Sounds like an idea worth trying. I'll check the docs and update

Comment: Not working. I have tried to delegate the task or the role itself, but ansible still tries to execute it from the current inventory machine

Comment: well, i tried a basic delegate_to task, that i run from host A (the ansible node) to host B, with delegation to host C and it worked as expected (a "shell: hostname" task). i dont know how the code inside `tasks/vms/revert_snap.yml` looks to comment more on your issue, but i guess you know better.

Comment: My scenario is different - I need ansible to delegate to host C without going through host B. Try your test where host B is unreachable. I need this because host C (the Hypervisor) turns on host B, so it is unreachable at the beginning of the playbook

Comment: oh i see, that's a very challenging scenario and i am out of ideas. maybe you can rewrite all the code for single host, and loop it externally (execute the playbook X times for the X VMs you have) and be done with it.